# Umbraco XSLT. Dynamic menu

Tags: xslt, xpath, umbraco

My Umbraco project has following structure:

```
Content
-Home
--Contacts
--Offices
-About
```

Home has '/' address, and is an Index page.
Can somebody tell me how to get Both - Home and About elements to put them into menu, through XSLT?
Currently i can take only subnodes by level of current page, which is Home, so i get only Contacts and Offices. I can't take'em by documentType, because i want a dynamic, and not a hardcoded one.
Is there a way to get Home and About constantly for display in menu?
I'm completly new to XSLT, and second day in Umbraco itself.

Edit: Here is a part of XML, under

```
<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>

<!-- Input the documenttype you want here -->
<xsl:variable name="level" select="1"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

<!-- The fun starts here -->
<ul>
<xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::* [@level=$level]/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">
    <xsl:if test="$currentPage/@id = @id">
        <li class="selected">
            <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
                <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
            </a>
        </li>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$currentPage/@id != @id">
        <li>
            <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
                <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
            </a>
        </li>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="$currentPage/id"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</ul>

</xsl:template>
```

Edit2: By taking off level equality, i've got "self", which is "Home", but still no "About".
Maybe you know how to find info about "X-Path" selector such as "ancestor-or-self::*"?

Comment: Can you post the XML you're trying to transform

Comment: XML markup is posted. Hope it'll help.

Comment: I was thinking more of the raw XML your source sends to the XSL file rather than the XSL itself.  In the sample you've given though, you might find xsl:choose a better option than xsl:if - see  http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_choose.asp

Comment: I know XSLT, I don't know Umbraco at all.  Wtiting XSL without any real idea of what the XML source looks like is something I'd have thought was almost impossible, but I;ve had a look at the Umbraco documentation and they seem to be suggesting you do precisely that.  I've edited your question to show a much simpler way of doing your list item, sorry I can't offer an answer

Comment: Thanks for that comment, it helped with simplyfying a markup a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've finaly found an answer.
The way to access all elements through a project root element is using of "$currentPage/ancestor::root//*".
That's how my markup looks now, with a help of John, in simplyfying 'if' statement.

```
<!-- Input the documenttype you want here -->
<xsl:variable name="level" select="1"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

<!-- The fun starts here -->
<ul>
    <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/ancestor::root//*  [@level = $level and name() != 'Home' and @isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">
        <li>
            <xsl:if test="$currentPage/@id = @id">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">selected</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
                <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
            </a>
        </li>
    <xsl:value-of select="$currentPage/id"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</ul>
```

On the exit i'm getting all elements of "content" except "Home" (i just don't simply need it in my menu).

Comment: any idea on working with sub menus as i have few sub menus withing the menus and this is giving me only the parent menus not the child.

Comment: Could you provide more info on this one? Maybe evem a snippet of code you have?